# Excel VBA to fill a column with formula until (last filled cell in another column)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

So I have an Excel Sheet, Column A is filled with data (the range is different everytime)
I want to fill the empty col H with formula (from H2 to the last filled cell in colA)

This is the code where I referred from multiple sites.
But it only filled H1 and H2, where I want H2:H6 in this case.
Current output using xlUp.
colC,D,E,F are something that can be ignored at the moment.

[image: This is the current output using xlUp]

I tried to change xlUp to xlDown.
It worked but it filled every cell from H2 to H(infinity), when some of data in colA stop at row60.

```
Sub Try()

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Range("H2:H" & lRow).Select
Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-6])/(RC[-1])"

Range("H2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H" & lRow)

End Sub
```

Can anyone please point out my mistake?

I know some of the method using Active Cells, but I don't want to use it because sometimes I don't know where my active cell is? like I dont know which cell is currently selected. (please let me know if I got the wrong idea of active cell)

Thank you.

Comment: Try to debug your code and check value of `lRow`. Also using unspecified `Range` and `Rows` object is a very bad practice, you should always use a worksheet object, e.g.: `set ws = Worksheets("ws name")` `ws.Range(..)` `ws.Rows.Count` ...

Comment: It's a shot in the dark because reading a paragraph is more difficult to understand on theoretical graphs. Try uploading a picture, or a link to one, it's worth more than a thousand words. Also, try using Cells(row, col).value, rather than Range("A1").FormulaR1c1. Using Cells you don't waste resources moving around Excel grids, rather is knows where to go "underneath". Also instread of xlup or xldown, you could just select the range you want, then run the Macro (set range equals active selection). Or try: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/pausing_a_macro_to_get_a_user_selected_range/

Comment: Hi all, I have uploaded a picture, at the mean time, I will also try to debug accordingly. On a side note, I'm actually prefer not to have any user-input at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. It selects range of data in column A and then offsets it to the column H. This range will be given to the auto-fill.

```
Option Explicit

Dim rng As Range
Dim wsh As Worksheet

Sub Second_Try()

  Set wsh = Worksheets("Sheet4")
  wsh.Activate

  wsh.Cells(1, "H") = "ans."

  Set rng = Range(wsh.Cells(2, 1), wsh.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))

  Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 7)

  wsh.Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-6])/(RC[-1])"
  Range("H2").AutoFill Destination:=rng

  'instead of these last two rows you can simply use this:
  'rng.FormularR1C1 = "=(RC[-6])/(RC[-1])"

End Sub
```

I personally prefer this solution since it does not selects ranges and just deals with the cells till there's an empty cell.

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet

Sub Third_Try()

 Set wsh = Worksheets("Sheet4")

 i = 2
 While wsh.Cells(i, 1) <> ""

  wsh.Cells(i, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-6])/(RC[-1])"

  i = i + 1
 Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Masoud, both solutions worked perfectly. I'm going with Second try because in my next part of code, I'm referring H to perform some actions. Btw, would you mind to tell me what went wrong in my previous attempt that is not working ?

Comment: @ExcelNovice `lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` here you get the last row correctly (i.e. 6) but using `xlDown` you select all of the column A since you start from `Rows.Count`. Your code works fine if you get rid of the lines that are not necessary to avoid from selecting a range when you don't need it. Like selecting `Range("H2:H" & lRow)`; however, I would suggest sticking to more explicit way of coding to avoid from any errors in future.